# How to integrate the following and solve for $v$: $\frac{dv} {((kv^2)/m - g)} = dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, physics

I am trying to find the effect of air resistance on the projectile motion of an ice skater performing a jump (I am aware it technically isn't called a projectile motion once there is air resistance involved but for the sake of explaining it shortly, I will say it is).

I have found that $F\text{net} = m*a = kv^2 - mg$ , since gravity is acting downwards and air resistance acting upwards, k being some constant for air resistance. So for the math part:

$$\frac{dv} {((kv^2)/m - g)} = dt$$

I have done integration by substitution at first, by using u = kv^2/m - g and $du = (\frac{2kv}m)dv$ , however, I am not sure if this is the correct approach and even if it is, I am unable to solve the final equation I found for $v$:

$$\ln\left(\frac{kv^2}m - g\right)= \frac{t2kv}m$$

[steps I followed to integrate and solve for v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yI7b.png)

I essentially followed the steps I outlined in the attached image

If anyone can help I would appreciate it so much. Thank you!

Comment: If the ice skater is moving upward (i.e. when $v>0$) then the force due to air resistance and the force of gravity both point downward. On the other hand, if the ice skater is moving downward (i.e. when $v<0$), then the force of gravity still points downward while air resistance points upward. So you actually have that $F_{\text{net}}=-mg-kv|v|$ assuming, of course, that the magnitude of air resistance is directly proportional to the square of the object's velocity.

Comment: If the equation is correct, one can rewrite as $$a v^2-g-e^{2 t a v}=0, a=\frac km$$ which may not be solvable using [the W Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this [Riccati's equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=dv%2F%28a%20v%5E2-b%29%3Ddt) as a special type of first-order nonlinear differential equation and the solution
$$
v(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{b} \tanh\big(\sqrt{ab} (c_1+t)\big)}{\sqrt{a}}
$$
where

- $a=\frac{k}{m}$,
- $b=\frac{m g}{k}$ and
- $c_1$ is the integration constant.

Mind that [arctanh](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arctanh) has a special relationship to the logarithm.

Some straightforward rewrite and the results are as expected. $arctanh$ is the inverse of $tanh$.

Somewhat comfortable is this [with g, k and m](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=dv%2F%28k%20%28v%5E2%29%2Fm-g%29%3Ddt).

To do the solution is documented in done by wolframaplha too but in the paid for version.

There are of course sides that show the solution. For example [ode0123](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0123.pdf). That is a specialized side for ordinary differential equations.

This page offers some of the newest tricks available for Ricatti: [Riccati Differential Equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: A Ricatti equation is very general, so how does one find the solution if they did not have software?(+1)

Comment: @TymaGaidash Please, note that the name is “Riccati”. The word “ricatti” in Italian is the plural of “ricatto”, which means “blackmail”.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I mixed up some letters. How about the original question about the Riccati equation?